# How to get the questions from hot/week/month tab?

Tags: support

I am only interested in the questions from hot/week/month tab.

The iPhone app MyStacks can show week/month tab, but I did not find such API in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

In the documentation it tells you to set the sort parameter to hot, week or month (or votes, creation, featured, or activity (default))

EG:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?sort=hot